# why it giving me an error String index out of range

Tags: java

I am writing a method that word-wrapping all lines that are longer than 60 characters. If a line contains 112 characters, the method should replace it with two lines : one containing the first 60 characters and another containing the final 52 characters.

This is the text file that I am working on:

[EX9.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA9He.jpg)

and this is the program that I wrote :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EX9
{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("EX9.txt"));
      wordWrap(input);
   }

   public static void wordWrap(Scanner input)
   {
       while(input.hasNextLine())
       {
           String line = input.nextLine();
           if(line.length() <= 60)
           {
               System.out.println(line);
           }
           else
           {
               int leng_line = line.length();
               int sixty = 60;
               int count = 0;
               for(int i = 0 ; i < leng_line / 60 ; i += 1)
               {
                   System.out.print(line.substring(i*60, sixty));
                   sixty += 60;
               }
               System.out.print(line.substring(sixty,leng_line));
               System.out.println();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

and It is saying that

```
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -58
```

I am not sure why range is -58.
What am I missing?

Comment: when `i` is greater than `1`, then `line.substring(i*60, sixty)` then *beginIndex is larger than endIndex* - see javadocs for the exception being thrown

Comment: found issue in line.substring(i*60, sixty), substring function will throw an error once the value of "i" increases from 1 onward.

Comment: Note the following, which appears on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): ___DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.___ _- copy or type the text into the question_

Answer (score 1):

Kindly update the for loop condition to resolve this issue as follows-

```html
for(int i = 0 ; i < leng_line / 60 ; i += 1){
System.out.print(line.substring(i*60, i*60+sixty));
sixty += 60*i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 `System.out.print(line.substring(i * 60, sixty));` -->  `System.out.println(line.substring(i * 60, sixty));`

2 `System.out.print(line.substring(sixty,leng_line));` -->
`System.out.println(line.substring(leng_line / 60*60, leng_line));`

`System.out.print(line.substring(sixty,leng_line))`,sixty mabey > leng_line,so report error.

Answer (score 1):

Here, your code is failing at this line outside the while loop, Here you are incrementing the `sixty` every time in the loop and when you are out of the loop its value is more than the line's length.

```
System.out.print(line.substring(sixty,leng_line));  // leng_line > sixty
```

To avoid that you can subtract 60 from `sixty`.

```
System.out.print(line.substring(sixty-60,leng_line));
```

**Complete code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EX9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\asn\\Desktop\\zzz.txt"));
        wordWrap(input);
    }

    public static void wordWrap(Scanner input) {

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            if (line.length() <= 60) {
                System.out.println(line);
            } else {
                int leng_line = line.length();
                int sixty = 60;
                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < leng_line / 60; i += 1) {
                    System.out.println(line.substring(i * 60, sixty));
                    sixty += 60;
                }
                System.out.println(line.substring(sixty-60, leng_line));
            }
        }
    }
}
```